# Why does Bulk Insert block Update in MS SSIS?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, bulkinsert, upsert

I have an SSIS package set up like this:

[SSIS flow http://www.invativa.se/Images/Support/support.PNG](http://www.invativa.se/Images/Support/support.PNG)

If I run only the *New Rows* flow the Bulk Insert finishes without a problem, but as soon as i connect the *Live Rows* flow the package stalls indefinitely. When I check the activity monitor the *Update Newer Table Rows* task stalls, blocked by the *Insert New Rows* task.

Why does the Bulk Insert not finish? What can I do tho make the package execute?

***NB:*** I'm well aware that this might not be optimal, but I'm really interested in getting answers to the question as it is stated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, I would say the New Rows bulk insert operation is putting a table lock on the target table, and therefore, the other operation cannot finish until the table lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

If you double click the Insert new rows task, you will see a check box that says table lock. Try unchecking it.